# como definir espaçamento no eixo da direita highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

eu tenho este gráfico no highcharts:

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/usdeur.json', function (data) {

    var startDate = new Date(data[data.length - 1][0]), // Get year of last data point
        minRate = 1,
        maxRate = 0,
        startPeriod,
        date,
        rate,
        index;

    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 3); // a quarter of a year before last data point
    startPeriod = Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());

    for (index = data.length - 1; index >= 0; index = index - 1) {
        date = data[index][0]; // data[i][0] is date
        rate = data[index][1]; // data[i][1] is exchange rate
        if (date < startPeriod) {
            break; // stop measuring highs and lows
        }
        if (rate > maxRate) {
            maxRate = rate;
        }
        if (rate < minRate) {
            minRate = rate;
        }
    }

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            },
            opposite: false,           
            plotLines: [{
                value: minRate,
                color: 'green',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: 'Last quarter minimum'
                }
            }, {
                value: maxRate,
                color: 'red',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: 'Last quarter maximum'
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 4
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

e gostaria de colocar eixo na direita utulizei este codigo: `opposite: true,` e ficou assim:

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/usdeur.json', function (data) {

    var startDate = new Date(data[data.length - 1][0]), // Get year of last data point
        minRate = 1,
        maxRate = 0,
        startPeriod,
        date,
        rate,
        index;

    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 3); // a quarter of a year before last data point
    startPeriod = Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());

    for (index = data.length - 1; index >= 0; index = index - 1) {
        date = data[index][0]; // data[i][0] is date
        rate = data[index][1]; // data[i][1] is exchange rate
        if (date < startPeriod) {
            break; // stop measuring highs and lows
        }
        if (rate > maxRate) {
            maxRate = rate;
        }
        if (rate < minRate) {
            minRate = rate;
        }
    }

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            },
            opposite: true,           
            plotLines: [{
                value: minRate,
                color: 'green',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: 'Last quarter minimum'
                }
            }, {
                value: maxRate,
                color: 'red',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: 'Last quarter maximum'
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 4
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

como eu deixo ele com a margem correta, pois assim ele fica dentro do grafico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O *Highstock* tem esse comportamento normal quando você posiciona o eixo Y à direita. Já no *Highchart* o eixo Y fica fora do gráfico com `opposite: true`.

O que você pode fazer é usar dois callbacks da API chamando uma função para reposicionar de forma programática os elementos alterando seus atributos (veja explicação nos comentários do código). Também é necessário adicionar uma margem à direita para caber os números e o título do eixo Y reposicionado:

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/usdeur.json', function (data) {

   function realinhar(){
      $(".highcharts-yaxis-labels text")
      .attr({
         "text-anchor": "", // apaga o atributo text-anchor para alinhar o texto à esquerda
         "transform": "translate(15,0)" // 15 pixels de margem à esquerda
      });

      // posicionamento do título
      var xAttr = $("text.highcharts-axis-title").attr("x"); // pego o valor do atributo x
      var yAttr = $("text.highcharts-axis-title").attr("y"); // pego o valor do atributo x
      $("text.highcharts-axis-title")
      .attr({
         "transform": "translate(40,0) rotate(90 "+ xAttr +" "+ yAttr +")" // 40 pixels de margem à esquerda
      });

   }

    var startDate = new Date(data[data.length - 1][0]), // Get year of last data point
        minRate = 1,
        maxRate = 0,
        startPeriod,
        date,
        rate,
        index;

    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 3); // a quarter of a year before last data point
    startPeriod = Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());

    for (index = data.length - 1; index >= 0; index = index - 1) {
        date = data[index][0]; // data[i][0] is date
        rate = data[index][1]; // data[i][1] is exchange rate
        if (date < startPeriod) {
            break; // stop measuring highs and lows
        }
        if (rate > maxRate) {
            maxRate = rate;
        }
        if (rate < minRate) {
            minRate = rate;
        }
    }

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
      chart: {
        marginRight: 80, // adiconar uma margem à direita
        events: {
           redraw: function(){ // callback quando o gráfico é alterado
              realinhar();
           }
        }
       },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            },
            opposite: true,           
            plotLines: [{
                value: minRate,
                color: 'green',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: 'Last quarter minimum'
                }
            }, {
                value: maxRate,
                color: 'red',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: 'Last quarter maximum'
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 4
            }
        }]
    },function(){ // callback quando o gráfico terminar de ser carregado
       realinhar();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Comment: Sensacional! muito obrigado :D